# How do I create a dictionary from two parallel strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two text files, which are formatted like so:

```
foo,bar,etc
```

the other one is like this:

```
1,2,3
```

and I want to put these two text files into one dictionary for Python without having to do each one by hand. I want the output to connect the strings to the numbers. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 12):

```
keys = first_string.split(',')
values = second_string.split(',')
output_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

---

```
>>> first_string = "foo,bar,etc"
>>> second_string = "1,2,3"
>>> keys = first_string.split(',')
>>> values = second_string.split(',')
>>> output_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> output_dict
{'etc': '3', 'foo': '1', 'bar': '2'}
```

---

If you want the values to be actual numbers, you can convert them:

```
values = [int(v) for v in second_string.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you know how to read the data from the file and split the lines into list, and convert them to `int`s as necessary.

```
s1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'etc']
n1 = [1, 2, 3]
dict(zip(s1, n1))
```

yields:

```
{'bar': 2, 'etc': 3, 'foo': 1}
```

*Notes*:

[zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) combines your lists:

```
zip(s1, n1)
[('foo', 1), ('bar', 2), ('etc', 3)]
```

In case you are not comfortable with creating lists from your lines data, for a given line using [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) you can just do

```
line = line.split(',') #'foo,bar,etc' => ['foo','bar','etc'] / '1,2,3' => ['1','2','3']
```

and if you want to convert your numeric data to `int`s use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
n1 = [int(n) for n in line] # ['1','2','3'] => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, same as above, his was more detailed, but both were helpful thank you.

Comment: Since you were here more recently, I thought I'd ask, it seemed to have worked in the beginning, but the order is messed up.

IE: string 1: test,test1,test2 string 2: 1,2,3

Instead of test being with 1, test would end up with 2, which doesn't work for me. Any other way to do this?

Comment: @EkanshVinaik You need to be more specific. What worked before, what order is messed up?

Comment: It created the dictionary, but the dictionary didn't keep the strings corresponding with each other, if that makes sense.

Comment: @EkanshVinaik Still a bit unclear, are you saying for example `bar` was associated with 2, and then later with some other value like 1?

Comment: No, it never associated itself with the right number (corresponding one). Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the values and keys directly from the text files, a sample code would be :

```
import fileinput

keys = []
values = []

for line in fileinput.input(['v.txt']):
    values = values + [int(v) for v in line.split(',')]

for line in fileinput.input(['k.txt']):
    keys = keys + [k.replace("\n","") for k in line.split(',')]

the_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

I assume that you need the values as integers, and the text files may contain multiple lines but they must contain the same number of elements.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just starting out, but it might be more simple to just run the two together in a single line:

```
string_dict = {'etc': '3', 'foo': '1', 'bar': '2'}
```